How to get images from multiple links in json to page
Here I have a json file someone sent me called post.json in links like so:
https://i.sstatic.net/oTudWVlA.png
and this is content inside one of the links:
https://i.sstatic.net/65uLEtMB.png
and here is my Home page:


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import ImagesList from './ImagesList';

const Home = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/0')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                setImages(data);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching images:', error));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="side-content">
                <div>
                    <ImagesList images={images} image="Images" />
                </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;



also here's my ImagesList page


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import './ImagesList.css'
const ImageList = ({ images, title }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <div className="image-grid">
                {images.map((image, index) => (
                    <div key={index} className="image-list">
                        <div className="image">
                            <div className="img-size">
                        <img className="img-margin" src={image.file_url} alt={image.title} width={150}/>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <div className="title" style={{ color: image.titleColor }}>
                        <center>{image.title}</center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ImageList;



the problem is Idk how to fetch data when json's in multiple links like that. Also this is how to images are supposed to show up, it's like a search results page but there's no search function yet (with my flex in css):
https://i.sstatic.net/AdK3Qg8J.png
how do I get content inside of this json file and I'm supposed to use jpeg_url or file_url from json file? thankyou so much <3

If my understanding of your question is correct, you want to show data from all json files 0/, 1/, ..., /20 at once with your ImagesList.
In that case I would suggest creating a separate function to fetch a single file, and another one to fetch and merge results from all files (note I am using async/await here which should be supported well on most browsers):
const Home = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
 
    const fetchImage = async (id) => {
        try {   
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/${id}`);
            const data = await response.json();
            return data;
        } catch(err) {
            console.error('Error fetching image:', err);
            return null;
        }
    }

    const fetchAllImages = async () => {
        const fetchImagePromises = [];

        for (let i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            fetchImagePromises.push(fetchImage(i));
        }

        const images = await Promise.all(fetchImagePromises);
        const validImages = images.filter(image => image !== null);
        setImages(validImages);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAllImages();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="side-content">
                <div>
                    <ImagesList images={images} image="Images" />
                </div>
        </div>
    );
};

Please note that such code still can be improved further by:

Moving API calls to separate module
I am not sure about the nature of your JSON server, but it's common for REST/JSON APIs to provide a single endpoint for fetching all entities at once. That would allow you to perform one request to fetch all images at once and save the bandwidth.


oh the thing is I am absolutely new to react and your answer here...Idk yet how to use but I will try my best to somehow use it, thankyou so much

omg thankyou so much it works :0
